# compute the correlation by 3 days ahead and not by matching day

Tags: r

so I have two datasets, scores1 and scores2

```
> print(scores1)
         Date    Value
1  2015-10-20 0.267606
2  2015-10-21 0.550725
3  2015-10-23 0.323529
4  2015-10-24 0.733333
5  2015-10-25 0.594937
6  2015-10-26 0.721311
7  2015-10-27 0.000000

.....


> print(scores2)
         Date    Value
1  2015-10-20 0.309859
2  2015-10-21 0.420290
3  2015-10-23 0.352941
4  2015-10-24 0.533333
5  2015-10-25 0.582278
6  2015-10-26 0.606557
7  2015-10-27 0.000000
...


scores1 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(16728, 16729, 16731, 16732, 
16733, 16734, 16735), class = "Date"), Value = c(0.267606, 0.550725, 
0.323529, 0.733333, 0.594937, 0.721311, 0)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

scores2 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(16728, 16729, 16731, 16732, 
16733, 16734, 16735), class = "Date"), Value = c(0.309859, 0.42029, 
0.352941, 0.533333, 0.582278, 0.606557, 0)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have merged both datasets by matching date and computed the correlation

```
mergedData <- merge(data, sentiment, by="Date")
x <- mergedData[,2]
y <- mergedData[,3]
cor.test(x, y)
```

Now I would like to compute the correlation but not by the matching date, but by 3 days ahead.

I tried to create a `data.frame` but that would just put both datasets together as such:

```
        Date    Value     Date.1  Value.1
1  2015-10-20 0.267606 2015-10-20 0.267606
2  2015-10-21 0.550725 2015-10-21 0.550725
3  2015-10-23 0.323529 2015-10-23 0.323529
4  2015-10-24 0.733333 2015-10-24 0.733333
5  2015-10-25 0.594937 2015-10-25 0.594937
6  2015-10-26 0.721311 2015-10-26 0.721311
7  2015-10-27 0.000000 2015-10-27 0.000000
```

is there a way to create a new data frame like the one above but the two datasets will be aligned by 3 days difference, more like:

```
         Date    Value     Date.1  Value.1
1  2015-10-20 0.267606 2015-10-23 0.323529
```

But for all of them

or is there another way that allows me to compute the correlation between two datasets with 3 days difference between both ?

Comment: Add 3 to one of the dates before doing the merge?

Comment: I do not understand can you expand please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will merge with dates shifted by 3:

```
m = merge(scores1, transform(scores2, Date = Date + 3), by="Date")

        Date  Value.x  Value.y
1 2015-10-23 0.323529 0.309859
2 2015-10-24 0.733333 0.420290
3 2015-10-26 0.721311 0.352941
4 2015-10-27 0.000000 0.533333
```

Then you can do `cor(m[, -1])`.

---

If it doesn't work, it's probably because your "Date" columns are not of class `Date`, so...

```
scores1$Date = as.Date(scores1$Date)
scores2$Date = as.Date(scores2$Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [lag function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lag.html) to create a new date variable with a 3 day lag

```
mergedData$lag3 <- lag(mergedData$Value, 3)
```

Then compute the correlation with that value.